# sqlsrv php not installing properly

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am trying to connect to my MS sql server through php.

I have set up a webserver and installed php using WAMP. I downloaded sqlsrv dll and added them to ext folder and then included it in php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

I can see that it's installed through WAMP:

[image]

However, when I check my phpinfo(), I don't see any reference to sqlsrv.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Yes, restarted it multiple times and still didn't work.

Comment: check the error logs and see if it ever loaded. just because it's checked off somewhere doesn't mean php can actually use it.

Comment: @MarcB - I am getting this error:
[08-Jun-2015 19:51:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_nts.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: You most likely have the wrong dll (the one you have might have been built for a different platform (e.g. 64 bit))

Comment: @honerlawd - i  downloaded from MSFT site so not sure where to get the correct version from.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @honerlawd - Windows 7

Comment: Follow this to install and configure it. http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php . You need to know what type of PHP you are using (Thread Safe or Non Thread Safe) and if you are running 32 bit or 64 bit OS.

Comment: @honerlawd - Thanks the problem is solved now. I was using the 64bit version of WAMP and I think the dll was 32bit. I switched to 32bit version of Wamp and it works now!